# BlockingCollection with GetConsumingEnumerable

Tags: multithreading, c#-4.0, concurrency

I'm using a BlockingCollection to insert some values that are processed using some threads.

Sometimes I have to take a "snapshot" of this collection to check some results.. so I do something like this:

```
IEnumerable<SourceResult> response = m_response.GetConsumingEnumerable();
IEnumerable<string>       results  = response.Where(i => i.source == "TEST1" || i.source == "TEST2").Select(i => i.json).DefaultIfEmpty(null);

if (results != null && results.Count() > 0)
{
    // CODE
}
```

When the code reaches this IF statement, the application freezes.

Why? Seems that response is locked forever.

Any ideas? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Where exactly are you using the BlockingCollection type ?

Comment: Outside thread loops @MarcelloGrechiLins =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.GetConsumingEnumerable()` produces the "blocking" enumerable that the collection gets its name from. In short you are using the wrong collection.

The way you use `BlockingCollection` is to put a thread on it to run a loop.

```
foreach(var item in blockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
{
    //do some work
}
```

Then using other threads you place objects onto the blocking collection. It is called a "blocking collection" because its enumerator blocks (sleeps) when it hits the last objects and then waits until a new item is added to the list.

The only way out of the for each loop is you call `.CompleteAdding()` on the blocking collection. Since `IEnumerable.Count()` is in effect just...

```
var count = 0;
foreach(var item in list)
{
   count++;
}
return count;
```

Your code is blocking on a foreach loop in the if statement (and waiting for you to call `.CompleteAdding()`).

I suspect you ACTUALLY wanted something more like `ConcurrentBag`.

Comment: Wow! That helped me a lot @Aron.. thank you! Actually I was using ConcurrentBag at first but I was afraid I couldn´t do a foreach loop while Enqueuing objects =)